# dropped geometry_columns and geography_columns tables

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgis-installation

(cross-posted from https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/320977/104667)

I've accidentally dropped `geometry_columns` and `geography_columns` tables from an existing PostgreSQL PostGIS database schema - let's call it mydb.myschema.

[This post](https://vilimpoc.org/blog/2012/12/04/spatial_ref_sys-and-geometry_columns/) outlines how to restore using `CREATE TABLE ...` with .sql from PostGIS install (I am on a shared server and am having to get my devops to look for them because of permissions).

I wanted to check if this will work. Also, do these two tables (`geometry_columns` and `geography_columns`) contain data relating to the geometries held in existing tables in mydb.myschema. Or do `geometry_columns` and `geography_columns` hold reference information for spatial operations?

Advice from anyone who has gone through this before welcome.

Running Postgis 2.5.2 ON pg 11.x.

[NOTE: No backup available as snapshots weren't set up beforehand...]

Comment: Found SQL on my server to re-generate these two as VIEWS. So the tables hold information about geometry as per OGC Simple Features specification see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/54849/104667. Is there anything I've missed though I wonder?